# Delete todo from state array react

Tags: reactjs, state

I am building an simple todo app to practise `reactjs` I have 3 components which looks like this:

Here is the TodoAppComponent.js which is the wrapper of the other two components:

```
import AddTodoComponent from '../AddTodoComponent/AddTodoComponent';

class TodoAppComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                        <h1 className="m-b-md">What needs to be done?</h1>

                        <AddTodoComponent></AddTodoComponent>
                    </div>                         
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoAppComponent;
```

An AddTodoComponent.jsx where I can add an todo:

```
import TodoItemComponent from '../TodoItemComponent/TodoItemComponent';

class AddTodoComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            todo: '',
            todoArray: []
        };
    }

    addTodo(e){
        this.setState({ todo: e.target.value });
        this.state.todoArray.push(<TodoItemComponent todo={this.state.todo}></TodoItemComponent>);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ todo: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (            
            <div>
                <div className="input-group m-b-md">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control add-todo" placeholder="Todo..." value={this.state.todo} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button className="btn btn-react" type="button" onClick={this.addTodo.bind(this)}>Add</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.state.todoArray}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddTodoComponent;
```

As you see I push the `TodoItemComponent` to an state array.

Here is the TodoItemComponent.jsx:

```
class TodoItemComponent extends Component {
  deleteTodo(){
    // this.setState({
    //   data: update(this.state.data, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})
    // })
  }

  render() {      
    console.log(this.props.todo, this.props.title);

    return (
        <div>            
            <li className="list-group-item todo-item">
                <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-md">
                    <span className="fa fa-check"></span>
                </button>
                {this.props.todo}
                <span className="pull-right">
                    <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle m-r-xs">
                        <span className="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span>
                    </button>

                    <button className="btn btn-xs btn-react btn-circle" onClick={this.deleteTodo()}>
                        <span className="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </li>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoItemComponent;
```

As you see I have a button where I can delete the todo item. But how can I acces the state in this file to delete it from the state array?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?you are already getting state in your component

Comment: Yes but how can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 deleteTodo(){
   this.props.onDelete(this.props.todo);
  }
```

and in your**AdddTodoComponent**

```
 addTodo(e){
        this.setState({ todo: e.target.value });
        this.state.todoArray.push(<TodoItemComponent onDelete={this.delete} todo={this.state.todo}></TodoItemComponent>);
    }

delete:function(index)
{

this.setState({
    //   data: update(this.state.data, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})
    // })
}
```

Comment: AddTodoComponent.jsx:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'todoArray' of undefined. That is in the update function in the method delete().

Comment: I tested it without the `setState` method but this delete(index) get triggered imediatly when I add an todo.

Comment: Ahh what I did in `TodoItemComponent` was imediatly invoke the method by doing this: `onClick={this.deleteTodo()}`. Than I changed it to: `onClick={this.deleteTodo}` where I throws me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Comment: It doesn't recognize `this.props.todo` in `deleteTodo()`

Comment: Could you please help me out?

Comment: do console.log(this.props.todo) and check if it is coming null or not

Comment: I get a response from `deleteTodo()` in TodoItemComponent it is null: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null And than I tried to .bind it and than looks like this: https://ibb.co/n0JkfQ. But than its it not recognized by `this.props.onDelete()`